# What is the behavior if External Org-wide sharing model is disabled?

Tags: force.com-sites, sharing, org-wide-defaults

If you don't have [External Org-Wide sharing models enabled](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_owd_external_setting.htm&type=5), what is the default behavior for external user?

Does it get the same value as whatever it the Org-Wide setting is?  Or is it defaulted to private.

I assume the former, but I can't find it stated anywhere explicitly and I just wanted to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your question:

> Does it get the same value as whatever it the Org-Wide setting is?

The answer to this is **Yes** based on the below excerpt from this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_owd_external_disable.htm) link (and some previous experiences). Even though it mentions “disabling” the feature but if External Sharing is not enabled at the first place, the OWD for the whole Org for all objects remains same as defined internally.

> Disabling External Organization-Wide Defaults results in **one** organization-wide default for each object.

You can verify this by changing the “Default Internal Access” (with External Sharing disabled), and see that the “Default External Access” gets changed accordingly.